# Using MySQL JSON field to join on a table

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I have a json field that stores a list of ids (not best practice here I know), I want to know if it's possible to use do operations on this JSON field and use them in the sql.

Below is a fictitious example of what I'm trying to achieve, is something like this doable?

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id INT,
    user_name VARCHAR(50),
    user_groups JSON
);

CREATE TABLE user_group (
    user_group_id INT,
    group_name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO user_group (user_group_id, group_name) VALUES (1, 'Group A');
INSERT INTO user_group (user_group_id, group_name) VALUES (2, 'Group B');
INSERT INTO user_group (user_group_id, group_name) VALUES (3, 'Group C');

INSERT INTO user (user_id, user_name, user_groups) VALUES (101, 'John', '[1,3]');
```

With the above data I would like to fashion a query that gives me the results like this:

```
user_id | user_name | user_group_id | group_name|
-------------------------------------------------
101     | John      | 1             | Group A
101     | John      | 3             | Group C
```

Some psuedo style SQL I'm thinking is below, though I still have no clue if this is possible, or what JSON functions mysql offers I would use to achieve this

```
 SELECT 
       u.user_id, 
       u.user_name, 
       g.user_group_id
       g.group_name
   FROM users u
   LEFT JOIN user_group g on g.user_group_id in some_json_function?(u.user_groups)
```

Let me know if the question isn't clear.

Comment: take a look at this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: not working in MariaDB 10.4.8

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With the help of Feras's comment and some fiddling:

```
  SELECT 
       u.user_id, 
       u.user_name, 
       g.user_group_id,
       g.group_name
   FROM user u
   LEFT JOIN user_group g on JSON_CONTAINS(u.user_groups, CAST(g.user_group_id as JSON), '$')
```

This appears to work, let me know if there's a better way.

Comment: I needed to do the same thing but join on a specific value in a JSON field and the following worked for me

`LEFT JOIN table b on JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(a.json_field, "$.json_value")) = b.mysql_value`

Comment: How optimized is this?

Comment: Missed comma after `g.user_group_id` and original table name is `user` not `userS`

Comment: This doesn't work when `user_group_id` is type `VARCHAR`

Comment: @AlexG To get this working with a string key column user_group_id, you need to add in double quotes around the value. JSON_CONTAINS(u.user_groups, CAST(CONCAT('"',g.user_group_id,'"') as JSON), '$')

Answer (score 8):

Funny, I got to the opposite solution compared to Kyle's.

I wrote my query like this:

```
SELECT 
       u.user_id, 
       u.user_name, 
       g.user_group_id,
       g.group_name
   FROM user u
   LEFT JOIN user_group g on JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(u.user_groups, '$')) = g.user_group_id;
```

It also works, and this solution doesn't need any transforming on the right side of the expression, this could provide a benefit in query optimizing in certain cases.

Answer (score 1):

For arrays like ["1", "2", "3"] that values are in string type, JSON_SEARCH function is the way for your question:

```
SELECT 
   u.user_id, 
   u.user_name, 
   g.user_group_id
   g.group_name
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_group g ON (JSON_SEARCH(u.user_groups, 'one', g.user_group_id))
```

JSON_CONTAINS function does not return true for integers as candidate parameter:

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(CAST('["1", "2", "3"]' AS JSON), CAST(1 AS JSON), '$')
```

returns 0 (false). You need to change it to this:

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(CAST('["1", "2", "3"]' AS JSON), CAST(CONCAT('"', 1, '"') AS JSON), '$')
```

But JSON_SEARCH can find the result:

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(CAST('["1", "2", "3"]' AS JSON), 'one', 1)
```

returns "$[0]" that means "true".

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried the following and it worked in `mysql 8.0.26`:

```
-- index
ALTER TABLE user ADD KEY ( (CAST(user_groups -> '$' AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)) );

SELECT * 
FROM user as a
left join user_group as t on t.user_group_id MEMBER OF (a.user_groups)
where t.group_name in ('Group A', 'Group C');
```

The query is based on the following `select` syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM t_json_arrays WHERE 3 MEMBER OF (c_array);
```

See examples on: https://saveriomiroddi.github.io/Storage-and-indexed-access-of-denormalized-columns-arrays-on-mysql-8.0-via-multi-valued-indexes/

Answer (score 0):

On maria DB 10:

```
SELECT 
    u.user_id, 
    u.user_name, 
    g.user_group_id,
    g.group_name
FROM user u
JOIN user_group g 
on JSON_CONTAINS(u.user_groups, CAST(g.user_group_id AS CHAR));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution when we use "string (char)" type array elements.(It works on MariaDB 11)

```
SELECT 
    u.user_id, 
    u.user_name, 
    g.user_group_id,
    g.group_name
FROM user u
JOIN user_group g 
on JSON_CONTAINS(u.user_groups, concat('"',g.user_group_id AS CHAR,'"'));
```

the key point is

```
concat(u.user_groups, concat('"',g.user_group_id AS CHAR,'"'));
```