# MySQL LEFT JOIN ON JSON field

Tags: mysql, json, left-join

I need to select all group names which user is associated with.

Tried every possible solution, but none of them work.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `groups` json NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `groups`) VALUES('U-1001', 'John Doe', '[\"G-9001\", \"G-9003\"]');

INSERT INTO `groups` (`id`, `name`) VALUES('G-9001', 'Group 1');
INSERT INTO `groups` (`id`, `name`) VALUES('G-9002', 'Group 2');
INSERT INTO `groups` (`id`, `name`) VALUES('G-9003', 'Group 3');
```

This solution works: [Using MySQL JSON field to join on a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818296/using-mysql-json-field-to-join-on-a-table)

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, g.name AS groupname
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN groups g ON JSON_CONTAINS(u.groups, CAST(g.id as JSON), '$')
```

But only when I change all `id` columns to type `INT` and change `groups` JSON value to `[9001,9003]`, otherwise I get:

```
ERROR 3141 (22032): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function cast_as_json: "Invalid value." at position 0.
```

Unfortunately, `id` columns must stay as type `VARCHAR`.

Expected result:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| id     | name     | groupname |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| U-1001 | John Doe | Group 1   |
| U-1001 | John Doe | Group 3   |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was just missing the quotes around `g.id`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, g.name AS groupname
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN groups g ON JSON_CONTAINS(u.groups, JSON_QUOTE(g.id), '$')
```