# Mysql Join on Json Type field

Tags: mysql, sql, json, join, left-join

I am kind of new in MYSQL and stuck in below problem

I have two tables Users and Groups and have stored group ids in user table like this:

```
{"ids": ["2", "4"]}
```

And I am trying to Join Groups table with User to get Group name from it.

I have tried somthing like this:

```
SELECT user.name, groups.name
  FROM user
  LEFT JOIN groups 
    ON JSON_CONTAINS(user.group_ids->'$.ids[*]', CAST(groups.id AS JSON))
```

but its not working, Please help on this.

Thanks

Comment: I think already answered into the below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818296/using-mysql-json-field-to-join-on-a-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `JSON_SEARCH()` for this:

```
SELECT u.name, g.name 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN groups g 
    ON JSON_SEARCH(u.group_ids -> '$.ids', 'one', g.id)
```

Comment: JSON_SEARCH() cannot return zero or empty string (only non-empty string or NULL return is possible), so IS NOT NULL compare is excess.

Comment: @Akina: agreed. I modified my answer.