# Mysql: Use JSON field to join 2 tables

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-json

I have 2 tables: Users table

```
id | groups    |
---------------
1  | ["1","2"] |     
2  | ["2"]     |
```

Groups table

```
id | name | 
-----------
1  | Test | 
2  | Jest |
```

I need to fetch the records from groups table, given an ID from the users table. Mostly single line SQL queries is preferred, but if not possible I can work with a stored procedure too.

I have found a way where there are no quotes for each ID's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818296/using-mysql-json-field-to-join-on-a-table). But I need the query to work with quotes.

Mysql version used is 5.7

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html

Comment: Please clarify which version of MySQL you are using. Run the query `SELECT @@version;` and report what it says.

Comment: @ysth the syntax seems a little tricky. Can you try to write the query for my usecase?

Comment: @BillKarwin 5.7. Added it in the question. Thanks

Comment: 5.7 does not support json_table.  it is also past end of life and no longer receiving security updates; you should consider it insecure and plan to upgrade as soon as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSON_search:

```
select u.id as "user id", g.id as "groups id", g.name as "group name"
from Users u
  join `Groups` g on JSON_search(u.groups, 'ALL', g.id);
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t3PpViaB).

In MySQL 5.7 you can use FIND_IN_SET which will be slower but works:

```
select u.id as "user id", g.id as "groups id", g.name as "group name"
from Users u
  join `Groups` g on find_in_set( g.id, replace(replace(replace(replace(u.groups, ']', '' ), '[', ''), '"', ''), ' ', '') )
```

Answer (score 1):

This task is awkward on MySQL 5.7 because it lacks a way to "explode" a JSON array into rows.

Exploding a JSON array can be done with a MySQL 8.0 function, JSON_TABLE() but that function is not implemented in MySQL 5.7 (which to be fair, is now past its end of life after October 2023).

So you have to extract each of the elements of the JSON array one by one, using a set of integer values in a JSON path like `'$[0]'`, `'$[1]'`, and so on. As many integers as the longest JSON array.

```
create table users (
  id int primary key,
  `groups` json
);

insert into users values
(1, '["1","2"]'),
(2, '["2"]');

create table `groups` (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(10)
);

insert into `groups` values
(1, 'Test'),
(2, 'Jest');

select u.id, g.name
from (
  select id, json_unquote(json_extract(`groups`, concat('$[', num-1, ']'))) as group_id
  from users
  cross join (
    select 1 as num union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
  ) as numbers
) as u
inner join `groups` as g on u.group_id = g.id;
```

Demo on MySQL 5.7: https://dbfiddle.uk/wZOVievD

If this seems like a lot of work, or the query is too inefficient, then just understand that this is the penalty for using JSON to store an array of values instead of a normalized table design with one value per row.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a many to many relationship to normalize your data.

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
    ,name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE group (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
    ,name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE group_and_user (
    group INT UNSIGNED
    ,user INT UNSIGNED
    ,PRIMARY KEY (group,user)
    ,FOREIGN KEY (group)
        REFERENCES group (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ,FOREIGN KEY (user)
        REFERENCES user (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

The third table will have the `vector` you want.

Comment: Seriously? To fix a problem, you can't tell me to remove the source. If it was so easy, I would have done it. Not sure if you have worked in the corporate world, but there are some things, you can't do.

Comment: That is a classic many to many relationship where you need a third table to store the relationships between users and groups. After a selection you could use GROUP_CONCAT to create a JSON vector.

Comment: It's true that it's hard to refactor a bad data design after it is incumbent and other code is depending on it. There may be no management support for doing such a change after it has gone to production. Nevertheless, I agree it should have been designed with a many-to-many table to begin with. JSON makes many queries harder.

Comment: @BillKarwin Agreed. If only, you were my boss